# Login on Red Hat Openshift image registry Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, redhat

I need some help or advise regarding the error I am encountering during login to my Red Hat Openshift's image registry. I am trying to commit a docker image to my image registry but during login executing the command below, no such host error is returned. Please see the error returned below

`docker login -u <my username -p $(oc whoami -t) image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000`

> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use
> --password-stdin. Error response from daemon: Get "https://image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/v2/": dial
> tcp: lookup image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc: no such host

Am I missing something or did I do something wrong. I checked my Red Hat Openshift console and my image reigtry service is running.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/configuring_red_hat_registry.html#using-service-accounts_configuring_red_hat_registry) fix your issue?

Comment: `image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc` is a cluster-internal URL. It would only be a URL accessible from directly inside the cluster. You need to ensure your registry is exposed through a Route/Ingress, and then `docker login` to that exposed URL.

Comment: @WillGordon, thank you very much. exposing my registry solved the issue. appreciate your support

Comment: @Jonnah, great! I've posted my comment as an answer. If it helped you, please consider marking it as an accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc` is a cluster-internal URL. It would only be a URL accessible from directly inside the cluster. You need to ensure your registry is exposed through a Route/Ingress, and then `docker login` to that exposed URL.

See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/latest/registry/securing-exposing-registry.html about exposing your registry, the tl;dr is

```
$ oc patch configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io/cluster --patch '{"spec":{"defaultRoute":true}}' --type=merge
```